# How to set the minimum width on a react material ui grid item?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've got this code... I'd like to have one 'column' that is a minimum of 250 pixels wide...  I tried the material ui suggestion for sizing: https://material-ui.com/system/sizing/ and didn't seem to have any luck... the 'logo' element will shrink smaller than 250px when the window size shrinks.  When that happens, the red grid item (which itself is a grid container with my actual data) obscures the logo.

How can I set the minimum width of a material ui Grid item?

```
<Grid
    container
    direction="row"
>
    <Grid item xs={3}  >
        <Box width={250}>
            <img src={Logo} key="logo" width="250"  height="100" alt="Logo" />
        </Box>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item style={{ backgroundColor: '#f22' }} xs={9}>
        <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="flex-start"
            spacing={2}
        >
        {this.panelGrid(eventID, panelData)}
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: style = {{minWidth: "250px"}}

Comment: <Grid item style={{ marginLeft|marginRight: 'auto' }}>...</Grid>

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this one:

```
<Grid item xs={3} sx={{minWidth: '250px'}}  >
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a minimum width of 250 pixels for a Material-UI Grid item, you can use CSS to define a minWidth property for the item's style. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
<Grid container direction="row">
    <Grid item xs={3} style={{ minWidth: 250 }}>
        <Box width={250}>
            <img src={Logo} key="logo" width="250" height="100" alt="Logo" />
        </Box>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item style={{ backgroundColor: '#f22' }} xs={9}>
        <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="flex-start"
            spacing={2}
        >
            {this.panelGrid(eventID, panelData)}
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS min-width. [The MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) has details.

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row">
<Grid item xs={3}  >
    <Box width={250}>
        <img src={Logo} key="logo" width="250"  height="100" alt="Logo" />
    </Box>
</Grid>
<Grid item style={{ backgroundColor: '#f22', min-width: '250px' }} xs={9}>
    <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        spacing={2}
    >
    {this.panelGrid(eventID, panelData)}
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```